# How to change timeout for connection_instance.Open() command?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

folks!

I'm working with Entity Framework (but it's actually doesn't matter) and multiple databases (ObjectContexts). One of the sql server has additional data, that is optional, and it can be sometimes offline.

When I'm trying to handle exceptions on any command when server if offline, I should wait 60 seconds on connection_instance.Open() command operating that gives me exception:

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. 
>   When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the
>   fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)

Can I somehow change this timeout time from 60 seconds to 5 seconds of another value? By the way, my entity framework time out connection is 2 seconds, but it's ignoring.

It's look like that this timeout set to whole system (maybe in windows register). I tryed to connect to this sql server via SQL Management Studio, and it tryed to connect 60 seconds too, and after got the same exception.

So, is there any way to change this timeout value? Or maybe thera another fast ways to check sqlserver state?

Comment: Does ObjectContext.CommandTimeout work ?                         /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the timeout value, in seconds, for all object context operations. A null value indicates that the default value of the underlying provider will be used.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Int32"/> value that is the timeout value, in seconds.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">The timeout value is less than 0. </exception>
    public int? CommandTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Does ObjectContext.CommandTimeout work ?

```
 /// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the timeout value, in seconds, for all object context operations. A null value indicates that the default value of the underlying provider will be used.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// An <see cref="T:System.Int32"/> value that is the timeout value, in seconds.
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">The timeout value is less than 0. </exception>
public int? CommandTimeout
```